# Error in setup with Botkit CMS and Botkit Web

Tags: botkit

I followed the official guide to connect Botkit Web and CMS and received the following error when sending a message in the *script* with name of **assortment** created in cms.

Does anyone know how to solve or can you give more details on how to debug?

> Error in trigger handler Error: DialogContext.beginDialog(): A dialog
>   with an id of 'Assortment:botkit-wrapper' wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

Error in trigger handler Error: DialogContext.beginDialog(): A dialog with an id of 'test:botkit-wrapper' wasn't found.

Anyone with  a solution? Experienced the same.